# Catch onMinimize Event For a Form (Delphi)

Tags: delphi, events, minimized

I found 2 ways for catching onMinimize event.

First: On FormResize event:

```
if MyForm.WindowState = wsMinimized then ......
```

Second: Declaring the message handler like this:

```
procedure WMSize(var Msg: TMessage); message WM_SIZE;
```

And then:

```
procedure TForm57.WMSize(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
  if Msg.WParam  = SIZE_MINIMIZED then ....
end;
```

Which way is better?!

Comment: The one which is better readable for you.

Comment: Which one is most optimized?

Comment: Don't worry about optimizing until you've identified a reason to do so (by profiling to track down an actual performance problem). Until then, do whichever is more readable and easiest to maintain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`OnResize` is fired in response to the same message (`WM_SIZE`). Unless you need to react before the VCL handles the message (update scrollbars, align controls etc.), you don't need to attach a message handler. Otherwise, be sure to handle it before the `inherited` call (which is missing in your sample).

Answer (score 1):

second is better. as WindowState is not necessarily wsMinimized.

Comment: Every WM_SIZE message will cause an OnResize event fired, whatever your window state is.